# Is there anyway/endpoint to create access_token in code for Dropbox SDK authorization?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk, dropbox-sdk-js

I am using dropbox javascript sdk for file uploads using following end points.
For file below 150MB

```
/upload
```

For file above 150MB

```
  /files/upload_session/start 
  /files/upload_session/append_v2
```

For Authorization, I am using the following code for now.

```
const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'my_access_token_created_manualy_from_app_console';
var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN, refresh_token });
```

Now I don't want to go to the app console every now and then to get access token.
Is there any way I could handle it in my code? Any API/ajax request to get access token in response to `app_key` and `app_secret`?

Answer (score 0):

Getting a Dropbox access token for a user's account always requires some initial manual interaction from the user to authorize the app in some way. This cannot be done entirely programmatically. For the developer's own account, such as in your case, you can generate an access token on the App Console. For arbitrary end-users, this is instead processed via the OAuth app authorization flow.

You can refer to [the OAuth Guide](https://www.dropbox.com/lp/developers/reference/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization) for more information. For the [Dropbox JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js) in particular, there's [an example of processing the OAuth flow here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/main/examples/javascript/auth/index.html).

Comment: I want to upload files to my own account. (in my scenario, Only one folder will be used always for the uploads. )  
@Greg will that make any difference ?

Comment: No, there still isn't a way to do this entirely programmatically, even if it's just for your own account. In that case though you can just do it manually once and then leave your access token/refresh token in your code though. You'd want to get "offline" access, and supply your app key and use the PKCE flow like in [this example](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/main/examples/javascript/PKCE-backend/code_flow_example.js) so the SDK will use the refresh token to refresh your access token for you automatically.